# Observing strange traffic

Tags: networking, wireshark

I observed in my private network some strange udp packages which are really confusing me. I was debugging some network issues and I found broadcasts from an unknown device. I just know the IP, but I cannot ping it. Even ARP fails!

There are regularly UDP packages from 192.168.12.34 (a0:02:dc:xx:yy:fd) UDP port 39224 to 192.168.12.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) 19132. Wireshark marks those packages as RAKNET with the content `ID_UNCONNECTED_PING`. I have no idea what is going on there. Do I have an hacked device or is that something normal?

Just thinking regarding that protocol I have installed riftcat which is somehow related with Oculus VR.

Comment: a0:02:dc:xx:yy:fd belongs to Amazon ...

Comment: I don't see anything strange.

Comment: according to [this message](https://www.amazon.com/forum/amazon%20discussions%20feedback?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=FxLCMW9UN2N6QR&cdThread=Tx1D17KFSXISFHK) `a0:02` is reported to belong to an `echo`. Don't know if this extends to `a0:02:dc` but you should know yourself what amazon hardware is present, kindle,dash,fire(tv) etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Wikipedia [List of TCP and UDP port numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) article, UDP port 19132 is the standard [Minecraft Pocket Edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft#Pocket_Edition) Multiplayer Server Port.  Perhaps this is the traffic you're seeing?

You don't mention the version of Wireshark you're running, but Wireshark has had support for this protocol since version 2.0.0 according to its [Display Filter Reference](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/m/mcpe.html) page, and you can even view the Wireshark [source code](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-mcpe.c;h=1f99be91041644890bdbd8085463508af9372157;hb=HEAD#l45) for this dissector and see the default port listed as 19132.